# passing multiple arguments to addCallBackElement Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there any way to add multiple arguments to an addCallBackElement() function in Google Scripts? I want to send information about what the user typed into a given text box, as well as an integer. Can I send both of these? If not, is there any way I can see what the user typed into a textbox without actually having a handler function? Thanks!

For example:

```
var count = 0
var handler = app.createServerHandler('myClickHandler').addCallbackElement(textBox, count);
```

Comment: Hey, can you provide an example like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This method is deprecated, is it not? According to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/server-handler) this is a deprecated functionality since 2014.

Comment: You might consider creating an object or an array of objects and send that as a single parameter then deconstructing on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, You can pass multiple argument as `array` in `withUserObject` method.

*Example*

```
<input type="button" value="Not Clicked"
      onclick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateButton)
          .withUserObject([this, 'Second Arg', 'Third Arg', ...])
          .getEmail()" />
```

Then you can access based on `array`'s index.

```
updateButton(email, args) {
 console.log(args); //[ButtonElement, 'Second Arg', 'Third Arg', ...];
 //Access it using
 const btn = args[0];
 const secArg = args[1];

 //or using es6's destructuring
 const [btn, secArg] = args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a standalone script or an add-on you can use something like this. Which utilises withUserObject(). The code comes [from this doc.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withUserObject(Object))

```
<input type="button" value="Not Clicked"
      onclick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateButton)
          .withUserObject(this)
          .getEmail()" />
```

The user's info is then included as the second argument in the success handler.

```
<script>
  // updateButton(fromServer, FromUser)
  function updateButton(email, button) {
    button.value = 'Clicked by ' + email;
  }
</script>
```